# Not able to insert hindi text in to oracle table?

Tags: oracle10g

I am not able to insert hindi text into `oracle` table from `sql plus`?

I am use `oracle` 10g database,I have create database with NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16.

and I have created a table which has `NCHAR` datatype column.

But when I try to insert hindi text into `NCHAR` column through sql plus, then data get inserted like '¿¿¿¿¿¿' instead if hindi text.

Please some body help me for solving it.

Comment: If you have just recently created the database, why did you use Windows-1252 as the database character set rather than creating the database with the UTF-8 character set?  Are you using Windows or Unix on your client?  sqlplus.exe or sqlplusw.exe if you're on Windows?  What are your Windows and DOS code pages?  What is your `NLS_LANG`?  Does `dump(your_column)` show that the data is stored correctly (and, thus, that it's just a display problem) or is the data stored incorrectly in the database?